# How to set the width in SwatchLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

How to set the width in SwatchLegend. Here is an easy example:

`SwatchLegend[63, Range[30], LegendLayout -> "Row"]`

I would like to prevent the line wrap.

Best wishes, Kerry

Comment: `SwatchLegend[63, Range[30], LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}]`

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot :)